# is there a recommended way for a app built using open source lwc to be deployed to salesforce with webpack / rollup / parcel?

Tags: lightning-web-components, open-source

I have tried to integrate twilio video into salesforce console . I managed to achieve this by building a react app and using lightning:container . The reason to do so is [twilio-video](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/tree/master/) was offered as a cjs package and there was no ES6 equivalent i could use to import it.

Is there a specific build configuration i can use that can convert packages similar to twilio-video to a bundle that i can deploy to salesforce and be able to interact with it natively without a lightning:container ?

Comment: i am not really getting your question to be honest. Do you want to know if there is a way to transform any package to native lwcs? somehow your headline does not match the content of your post

Comment: I want to use a cjs module within salesforce lwc and want to know if there is a way to use any of the popular bundlers to achieve it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use cjs modules as a static resource. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library.

Comment: When i tried to load the min.js from dist of https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/archive/2.0.0-beta12.zip , the load fails without any specific error . when i handle the exception it just shows undefined.  is there any way to debug this load ?

Comment: you can pause on exceptions via browser devtools - your library is using apis which are not supported in lockerservice. So no "native" support with lwc at all - workaround like alyways in that case aura component with max version of 39, lightning:container or iframed visualforce page

Comment: There seems no easy way to find out if a library is compatible with locker service .  Is there any way am missing ?Secondly if the loadScript fails because of locker service issue it doesn't give any errors around it . Is there any alternative like browserify equivalent that we can use to rebuild the library compatible with lwc and locker service ?

Comment: Try the Locker Console (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console) and Locker API viewer (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer). These combined with the tip above about pausing on (un)caught exceptions should be sufficient to tell you if a library is Locker compliant and, if not, why.